# Automatic imports in JDeveloper

Tags: java, import, package, jdeveloper

I recently started using JDeveloper & I come across this weird problem(I dont exactly know if it is weird or i'm doing something wrong)

I create this list object

```
private List a1 = new ArrayList();
```

Then I hover over `List & ArrayList` to find the import option, but they do not appear(it says `"Type 'List' not found" & "Type 'ArrayList' not found"`). 
JDeveloper gives me options to create a new class or interface but no option to import them. Is there anything specific that need to be set in JDeveloper to be able to get those. Same case with anything that I try to import. I hover & no appropriate option.

Comment: This may help you http://radio-weblogs.com/0128037/stories/2003/08/11/topTenToysForJavaCodersIn905.html

Comment: Thanks @SanKrish. Apparently, I was using the left alt wen i should have been using right alt+enter.
That helped, thanks a ton

Comment: sometimes simple things cause messy problems :)

Comment: totally agree. Well, I'm new to programming as well. Will probably make a lot of silly mistakes on the way to get good at java :)